# Debian install, mounting /var /tmp /home in the same partition

Tags: debian, mount, partition, symlink, bind-mount

I'm making a new Debian install. I have a SSD and an HDD. My idea was to put /home, /var and /tmp on the same partition in the HDD, and the rest (/) in a tiny partition in the SSD.

I followed this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266101) since it seemed reasonable, but all I managed was to mount a folder like "/var,/tmp,/home", that is, it created a folder "var,", then a folder "tmp," inside, then a folder "home" inside. Notice it took the commas as part of the names, and the whole thing as a single hierarchy like say, /usr/local.

Second thing I tried was to move the folders home, tmp and var into the HDD partition, mounted as /home+tmp+var via fstab, and create symlinks in / pointing to them. I managed to brick my Debian install since it seems PartedMagic didn't maintained the permissions of all those folders, so they all got copied as "root".

Any other ideas?

For instance, during a Windows 7 install, I moved Program Files and Users to a separate partition, making symlinks to them from C. Maybe something similar can be done in Debian? I poked around during the install on various folders but I couldn't notice anything that might help me.

I don't need to save the existing install, so there is no problem if I need to reinstall.